# Rewrite java method using reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I'm trying to rewrite the following java method that return a list of objects(hibenrate domain objects) to be more generic to just write it once and to be able to pass any object to it.

```
public List<GsCountry> getCountry() {   
    Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    List<GsCountry> countryList = new ArrayList<GsCountry>();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from GsCountry");
    countryList = (List<GsCountry>) query.list();
    return countryList;
}
```

how could I do that to be free to return a list of the type I passed as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//making the method name more generic
public List<E> getData() {   
    Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();

    // try to add a model final static field which could retrieve the 
    // correct value of the model. 
    Query query = session.createQuery("from " + E.model);
    result = (List<E>) query.list();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: if you want to get at E.model, you will need to add a parameter of type `Class<E>`. E alone won't help you because of type erasure.

Comment: `E.model` won't work, unless `E` is declared as `E extends SomeClass` where `SomeClass` declares a public `model` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code example, from [Don't repeat the DAO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html), you will find helpful.

```
public class GenericDaoHibernateImpl <T, PK extends Serializable>
    implements GenericDao<T, PK>, FinderExecutor {
    private Class<T> type;

    public GenericDaoHibernateImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public PK create(T o) {
        return (PK) getSession().save(o);
    }

    public T read(PK id) {
        return (T) getSession().get(type, id);
    }

    public void update(T o) {
        getSession().update(o);
    }

    public void delete(T o) {
        getSession().delete(o);
    }

    // Not showing implementations of getSession() and setSessionFactory()
}
```

Comment: I'm always surprised when I see this pattern is not used :-) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

[Jinesh Parekh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243235/rewrite-java-method-using-reflection/4243309#4243309) is good, but it's missing two details.

a) a class paramater is needed to implement the generic return type
b) there's no such construct as `E.model`, instead use `clazz.getSimpleName()`

```
public List<E> getData(Class<E> clazz) {
    // insert Jinesh Parekh's answer here
    // but replace E.model with clazz.getSimpleName()
}
```